# How to post JSON with "params" key in rspec using xhr?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, xmlhttprequest

I ran into a problem while testing a controller using xhr.

```
 it 'send request' do
    do_login :superguru

    xhr :post, :create,
        locale: :en,
        customer_id: customer.id,
        ...
        params: 'some,key'
  end
```

Stack trace:

```
 # /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4@energo/gems/actionpack-4.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in merge!'
 # /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4@energo/gems/actionpack-4.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in url_for'
 # /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4@energo/gems/actionpack-4.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:773:in `path_for'
 # /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4@energo/gems/actionpack-4.2.11/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:745:in `build_request_uri'
 # /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4@energo/gems/actionpack-4.2.11/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:634:in `process'
 # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:41:in `process_with_default_locale'
 # /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4@energo/gems/actionpack-4.2.11/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:67:in `process'
 # /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4@energo/gems/actionpack-4.2.11/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:520:in `post'
 # /Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4@energo/gems/actionpack-4.2.11/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:550:in `xml_http_request'
 # ./spec/controllers/api/meta/customers/data_series_import_configurations_controller_spec.rb:40:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Customers>'
```

Problem is in `/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4@energo/gems/actionpack-4.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802`, because there is

```
if options.key? :params
   params.merge! options[:params]
end
```

And `options[:params]` == 'some,key', which is a string. When I remove `params` from request, it passes. The same, when I change the `params` value to `Hash`.

But I really need to pass the string with `params` key. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: how do you pass the params as a Hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rails-5 style:

```
xhr :post, :create, params: { locale: :en, ... params: 'some,key' }
```

Comment: Thx, works! but `locale` and `customer_id` must be out side the `params` block.

Answer (score 0):

Second option was to use `params` key of type `String`, not `Symbol`